# Getting text from multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, xml, function, winforms, loops

I have 3 textboxes `ip_textBox`, `port_textBox`, `node_textBox` whose value is populated by reading the **App.Config** file. These are stored as Key,value pairs in  **App.Config** file. The format is as below.

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="IP"   value=" " /> // ip address comes here
    <add key="Port"  value="9999" />
    <add key="NodePath"  value="C:\\Desktop\\Test.js" />
  </appSettings>
```

Once I make changes, I need to save the textbox value back to the XML file.

I have a function `UpdateXml()`

```
 public static void UpdateXml(string key, string value)
        {
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
            config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
        }
```

which can be used to update the `App.Config` file on a button click event. My initial approach was by calling `UpdateXml()` function for each textbox value like below:

```
  private void Btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         string ip = ip_textBox.Text;
         string port = port_textBox.Text;
         string node = node_textBox.Text;
                
         UpdateXml("IP", ip);
         UpdateXml("Port", port);
         UpdateXml("NodePath", node );
        }
```

Since both arguments of `UpdateXml()` needs to be iterated over, I was wondering what will be the most efficient approach for saving all three in one go.

Comment: are these the only textboxes you have? are they together in a group box? there is a method which can extract all controls of the same type. This could be used, and your prefix of the textboxes names could be used as the key when saving

Comment: Yes, all the textboxes  are inside a tablelayoutpanel

Comment: are these the only textboxes inside that panel?

Comment: @MongZhu yes these are the only ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it like this, there is no need for a separate method.

```
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("IP", ip_textBox.Text);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Port", port_textBox.Text);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("NodePath", node_textBox.Text);
```

And if you really want to create a method then no need to use any parameters to the method, simply write the above lines in the method.

Comment: What about saving the Configuration? Does the changes reflect instantly or do I have to restart the application?

Comment: I haven’t tried that, I have answered your original question

Comment: Actually, .Add() method is appending the existing value with what am entering. config.AppSettings.Settings["IP"].Value = ip_textBox.Text is what I wanted. My mistake

Comment: I am not sure, but can you try `config.AppSettings.Settings["IP"] = ip_textBox.Text`?